# Rsnapshot Exclude Directory Not Working

Tags: linux, backup

Rsnapshot not excluding the files that I specified in exclude_file.

Config file

```
config_version  1.2
snapshot_root   /home/xxx/Backups/test/
cmd_cp  /bin/cp
cmd_rm  /bin/rm
cmd_rsync   /usr/bin/rsync
cmd_ssh /usr/bin/ssh
cmd_logger  /usr/bin/logger
cmd_du  /usr/bin/du
interval    hourly  6
interval    daily   7
interval    weekly  4
interval    monthly 3
verbose 2
loglevel    4
logfile /home/xxx/Desktop/local.log
exclude_file    /home/xxx/Desktop/local-exclude.txt
#rsync_long_args --delete --numeric-ids --delete-excluded
#lockfile   /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
backup_script   /home/xxx/Desktop/db-backup.sh  mysql/
backup  /var/www/dev/   test/
rsync_short_args    -avvv
```

local-exclude.txt

```
exclude downloader/*
exclude var/*
```

rsnapshot log file

```
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:44] /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c local-rsnapshot.conf hourly: started
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:44] Setting locale to POSIX "C"
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:44] mkdir -m 0755 -p /home/xxx/Backups/test/hourly.0/
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:44] mkdir -m 0755 -p /home/xxx/Backups/test/tmp/
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:44] cd /home/xxx/Backups/test/tmp/
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:44] /home/xxx/Desktop/db-backup.sh
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:46] cd /home/xxx/Backups/test/
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:46] sync_if_different("/home/xxx/Backups/test/tmp/", "/home/xxx/Backups/test/hourly.0/mysql/")
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:46] /bin/rm -rf /home/xxx/Backups/test/tmp/
[19/Apr/2012:11:42:46] /usr/bin/rsync -avvv --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/home/xxx/Desktop/local-exclude.txt /var/www/dev /home/xxx/Backups/test/hourly.0/test/
[19/Apr/2012:11:43:24] Some files and/or directories in /var/www/dev/ only transferred partially during rsync operation
[19/Apr/2012:11:43:24] touch /home/xxx/Backups/test/hourly.0/
[19/Apr/2012:11:43:24] WARNING: /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c local-rsnapshot.conf hourly: completed, but with some warnings
```

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you used the rsync syntax in the exclude file whereas
exclude patterns or globs are expected.

Quoting from `rsnapshot(1)`:

> exclude_file  /path/to/exclude/file
>
> This gets passed directly to rsync using the --exclude-from directive.
>   See the rsync(1) man page for the syntax.

And `rsync(1)` says:

> --exclude-from=FILE
>
> This option is related to the --exclude option, but it specifies a FILE
>   that contains exclude patterns (one per line). Blank lines in the file
>   and lines starting with ’;’ or ’#’ are ignored. If FILE is -, the list
>   will be read from standard input.

This is an example from my `exclude_file`:

```
*~
\#*#
*.bak
*.old
```

Since you are excluding by path, I would suggest putting a rsync-filter
in the appropriate directories, e.g. this is what I have in my home:

```
include_/.emacs.d/
exclude_/.emacs.d/auto-save-list
exclude_/.emacs.d/eshell
exclude_/.emacs.d/image-dired
exclude_/.emacs.d/thumbs
```